# proxy.config.json support parameters

Tags: angular-cli, http-proxy

Good morning.
After configuring the proxy, I was able to succesfully call the api.
the request loos like this: http://mydomain/jsonresponse.json
However there's another endpoint I'd like to call but it has a parameter like this:
http://mydomain/{id}/jsonresponse.json
This one didn't work

My configurations looks like this:

```
{
  "/current/*": {
    "target": "https://newdomain.com/",
    "secure": false,
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/current": "/jsonresponse.json",
      "^/id": "/jsonresponse.json"
    },
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

the call from the service:
var url = /${id}/id;
this.http.get(url);

As I mentioned the first request works but the second one doesn't.
I appreciate any help or guidance, since I haven't been able to find support for it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround if someone is interested
the Http call looks like this:

httpClient.get("/comic/current")

httpClient.get("/comic/id/${id}/info.0.json")

```
{    
    "/comic/*": {
      "target": "https://newdomain.com/",
      "secure": false,
      "pathRewrite": {       
        "^/comic/id/": "/",
        "^/comic/current": "/jsonresponse.json"
      },
        "changeOrigin": true
      }      
  }
```